# Node - gcm send silent notifications

Tags: node.js, node-gcm

I'm using node-gcm, https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gcm
But I cannot figure out if I can send silent notifications.
By 'silent' I mean that the app will be notified, but no notifications will be displayed to the user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think that's up to you to display the notification or not. could you post some portion of your code? so that its easier to find the problem.